# Kак отловить закрытие окна?

Tags: python, tkinter

Надо, чтобы при закрытии окна появлялся `askyesno` с вопросом "Вы уверены, что хотите закрыть окно?". Я пытался сделать нечто вроде этого:

```
root=Tk()
def ask(e):
    if e.x==200 and e.y==0:
        if askyesno(message='Вы уверены,что хотите закрыть окно?'):
            root.destroy()
root.bind('<Button-1>',ask)
```

Но я убедился, что значок крестика находится вне системы координат окна. Во всех более-менее серьёзных программах есть такие предупреждения, но в интернете я ничего лучше, чем убрать значок крестика и вместо этого поставить кнопку "Exit", я не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", function_on_close)
...
```